# Google Spreadsheets: IF not working

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-settings

I have problems with my `IF` command in Google Sheets. If gives `#ERROR!` all the time. See this simple test:

[image: Error screen shot]

Not even if I put in the number directly and avoid references:

[image: Error screen shot 2]

Am I using the `IF` wrong? Or what could such a problem be? This example is from a new document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed that you are in Denmark.

Do you by chance write one and a half as `1,5` rather than `1.5`?

If so, you need to use semi-colons rather than commas. Try:

```
=IF(3>1;1;0)
```

It's a locale issue as answered [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/SpvTKL-88Ks)

Comment: Great! Well spotted :) Thanks a lot for both answers.